# Returning a specific sum from an array of integers non-recursively

Tags: java, arrays, list, sum, combinations

I'm having issues finding a solution for a problem like this:

Array = [5, 10, 10, 15, 21]

requiredNumber = 46

Returned Result = [10, 15, 21] or [5, 10, 10, 21]

Is there a non-recursive way to return a combination of integers from the array that add up to 36? I'm trying to keep the implementation as simple as possible.

Comment: What are the issues?

Comment: Are the arrays always ordered? if so you can do some binary search and find the answer. Really useful for long arrays

Comment: The arrays will not always be ordered. The issue is implementing a solution that finds every single combination of these numbers and returns the set that adds up to the requiredNumber.

Comment: Depending on the size and amount of times you want to search that array you should consider sorting it first

Comment: [This solution might help.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36214/find-all-subsets-of-an-int-array-whose-sums-equal-a-given-target)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That solution uses recursion, I'm asking if there is a way to implement it without recursion.

Comment: Suggestion: your question is actually worth keeping, if you change it to something like : Non-recursive way to find combinations from a set

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a "non-recursive way to find all combination from a set of value"

Here is one way, in concept:

have a bit set with number of bits equals to number of elements in your set of value.  For example, for your case of 5 element array, you need 5 bits.

(View your bit set as an integer) Start from 0, and keep incrementing.  For each value, you get a combination of your set.

e.g.

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
for (bits 0b00000 to 0b11111) {
    sum array base on bits (only sum if corresponding bits turned on)

    if sum equals to desired value, then return 
}
```

If you are sure that your array is less than 31/63 values, then using an int/long will be super simple.  It is still easy if you want longer array, by using BigInteger (or BitSet maybe) for such purpose.

An example of hard-coded value, but it should give you the idea (haven't compiled, please bear with syntax errors :P ) :

```
int[] array = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};

for (int bits = 0; bits < 32; ++bits) {  // bits < 2^5
    System.out.print("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
       if ((bits & 1 << i) != 0)  {   // i-th bit is ON
           System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
       }
    }
    System.out.println(" ]");
}
```

above code should give you all combinations. It should be trivial to change to what you want to do (finding specific sum)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a specific reason why you chose bits < 32 in the first for-loop?

Comment: Because it is 2^5,  with 5 being the size of the array. Keep in mind that for long arrays the solution to your problem could be really slow

Comment: @EduardoJavierHuertaYero could be really slow because of...? excessive BigInteger objects created?  That can be an issue but it can be easily solved by implementing the "incrementation" logic on a BitSet.  Or are you referring any reason that can be slow? (I cannot think of any if compared to recursive approach)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. I was referring to the number of iterations. For an array with a few thousand elements it would take a while to complete the outer loop

Comment: @EduardoJavierHuertaYero It will not be better if you use recursion, as number of times recursion hit the base case is just the same as number of iteration we made here.

Comment: I partially agree, @AdrianShum. If you order the array first (wasting n log n), then you will have to test far less combinations, whether you are using recursion or not (btw, any recursive program can be expressed iteratively, only not as cleanly)

Comment: @EduardoJavierHuertaYero I think I got what you mean.  You are talking about the specific requirement from OP of finding sum (hence sorting will help to stop early if sum already exceed), while I was simply talking on general case of listing out all combination iteratively.  :)

Comment: @EduardoJavierHuertaYero but still, it is not "my approach" that makes it slow.  If such optimization is not done in recursive approach, it is equally slow, if not slower. Therefore, to be precise, you can say, "sorting the array first can give better performance when finding the expected sum", but not "the solution to your problem could be really slow" (because it is just the same for recursive approach)  :)

Comment: @AdrianShum, I have nothing against your approach, I'm actually the one that voted it up. I just noted that it has exponential complexity (2^N, N being the size of the array) and therefore not useful even for medium sized arrays. Since the original problem was not to find all combinations of sums, but to find the combinations that yielded a specific value, it is possible to build an algorithm (recursive or not) that solves the problem more efficiently by ordering the array first.